# Ncurses - how to add something into the input buffer

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

I want to add something to the user input buffer using ncurses (basically, the typeahead, before the user presses enter). I know there is a function `flushinp()`, which allows for clearing of the input buffer. Is there also a function that allows for me to add something to the buffer? My ultimate goal is to have command completion upon a press of the tab key.

Comment: I don't think there's such function available from ncurses natively. You're probably looking for something like this: https://github.com/Hipo/hst

Answer (score 1):

You can put (subject to an implementation-defined limit of) characters into the input queue using [`ungetch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Ungetting-characters) or [`unget_wch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html).

These are both in X/Open Curses, so they're reasonably portable.  X/Open only guarantees a single character, however:

- [ungetch, unget_wch - push a character onto the input queue](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/unget_wch.html)

The coverage of curses functions in Python's binding is incomplete; it documents only [`ungetch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.ungetch).